# What default encoding is assumed by XDocument.Load?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, base-class-library

If I use `XDocument.Load` to parse an XML file...

```
var x = XDocument.Load("somefile.xml");
```

...which *does not* have a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="..."?>` header...

```
<MyRootElement>
   ...
</MyRootElement>
```

...what is the default encoding assumed by `XDocument.Load`? ANSI (i.e. the system default legacy locale)? UTF-8? Something else?

I have [checked the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_Load_System_String_), but it's not documented there. I have also looked at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,8a0ff89671e31a9d), but gave up after getting too deep into the `XmlReader` source.

Comment: I'd at least *expect* it to follow the XML spec, and autodetect either UTF-8 or UTF-16: "Although an XML processor is required to read only entities in the UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings, it is recognized that other encodings are used around the world, and it may be desired for XML processors to read entities that use them. In the absence of external character encoding information (such as MIME headers), parsed entities which are stored in an encoding other than UTF-8 or UTF-16 must begin with a text declaration (see 4.3.1 The Text Declaration) containing an encoding declaration:"

Comment: It won't assume, it will autodetect. It will correctly handle UTF-16 with a BOM, for example. I don't have the code on hand, but if you're lucky it might actually [follow the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing). Of note: it will assume UTF-8 without a better indication, *not* `Encoding.Default`.

Comment: Ah, [here we go](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,2852). It specifically autodetects Unicode only. Also see the code after that; without a BOM it starts off in ASCII and later switches based on whether a declaration is present.

Comment: Note that even if the XML file contains no BOM and the XML declaration doesn't specify an encoding, `XDocument.Load()` will still correctly load an XML file that uses UTF8 encoding - even if some of the characters in the file have no ASCII equivalent.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks, that was a great starting point. Apparently, the reader uses SafeAsciiEncoder only for reading the `<?xml ...` header. If no such header is present, it [switches to UTF-8](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,3521).

Answer (score 6):

Internally, it [calls `XmlReader.Create(string, XmlReaderSettings)`](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/dotnet/corefx/src/System.Xml.XDocument/src/System/Xml/Linq/XDocument.cs#217). This gives it the same default as that method call. According to the link from [Jeroen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689504/what-default-encoding-is-assumed-by-xdocument-load/48690112#comment84377914_48689504), the encoding for stream input is auto-detected from the BOM (the [default being ASCII](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,2932) if there is no BOM).

However, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39026782/), the default encoding can be overridden by passing in a `TextWriter` (such as a `StreamWriter`):

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("somefile.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
var x = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Comment: Apparently, the reader uses SafeAsciiEncoder only for reading the `<?xml ...` header. If no such header is present, it [switches to UTF-8](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,3521).